# Django filter if weekend between range

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Destination_Deal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Nombre"),max_length=200)
    duration = models.IntegerField(_(u"Días"))

class Departure_Date(models.Model):
    date_from= models.DateField(_('Desde'))    
    date_to= models.DateField(_('Hasta'))
    destination_deal = models.ForeignKey(Destination_Deal,verbose_name = _("Oferta de Destino"))
```

I would like to filter Destination Deals that are suitable to travel in a weekend. That means:

Departure Day = Friday or Saturday
Return Day = Sunday. So duration must be 3 or 2 if departure day is Friday or Saturday.

**Example**

```
Destination_Deal
id  name        duration
1   Deal1       3
2   Deal2       5
3   Deal3       2
4   Deal4       7


Departure_Date
id  date_from   date_to     destination_deal_id
1   2012-11-05  2012-11-15  1
2   2012-11-01  2012-12-16  2
3   2013-01-21  2013-01-27  3
4   2013-01-14  2013-01-18  3
5   2013-01-04  2013-01-11  4
```

**Desired Result**
**ID1:** 2012-11-09 was Friday and the deal's duration is 3. So in this case, Friday, Saturday and Sunday conform a valid weekend.

**ID3:** 2013-01-26 is Saturday and the deal's duration is 2. Also is valid.

**--Edit--**
Ok, sorry if I was not clear. I need to filter the Destination Deals based on the above weekend rule. I was thinking to do it by getting the date_from from the model (DateField) to python (datetime), iterate it until date_to and use weekday() function to check if it is a Friday or Saturday.
 I am aware of django weekday function but it will only work on a specific date (no range) so I would like to know if there is a simpler approach for this scenario.

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: The question is: "I would like to filter Destination Deals that are suitable to travel in a weekend." I will update my post.

Comment: That's not a question.  You need to demonstrate or explain what you've already tried to solve this problem, and then ask a specific question about why what you've already tried didn't work.  If you are stuck to the point where you don't even know how to approach the problem, then figure out what specific question you have that needs to be answered for you to formulate an approach, and then ask that.  (Edit: it looks like you've elaborated a bit in your edit so I'll take a look at that)

Answer (score 0):

```
where = '(deparure_date__date_from - deparure_date__date_to) > 4 || \
         DAYOFWEEK(deparure_date__date_from) IN (1, 6, 7) || \
         DAYOFWEEK(deparure_date__date_to) IN (1, 6, 7)'

Destination_Deal.objects.filter(duration__in=[1, 2, 3]) \
                        .extra(where=[where])
```

- If duration in 1, 2, 3
- And If difference of `date_from` and `date_to` > 4 then definitely there is going to be either Friday, or Saturday or Sunday in between.
- or check if `date_from` is Friday, or Saturday or Sunday
- or `date_to` is Friday, or Saturday or Sunday

Comment: Ok, I know this can be a little confusing but the date_from and date_to conforms the range for the departure date only (not departure and return). So in Deal1 it is necessary to check 2012-11-05, 2012-11-06, 2012-11-07 ... 2012-11-15 to check if it has a Friday or Saturday as a valid departure day and also duration is 3 or 2.

Comment: To understand more please update your data as Deal4 has duration 3 but its from_date and to_date does not meet criteria.

Comment: Deal4 has duration 7. Deal2 and Deal4 does not meet criteria, that is the reason I wrote in "Desired Result" only ID1 and ID3